# Having an issue with a div background img

Tags: html, css

**CSS**

```
.content {
    background-image: url("Pics/GameLogoBackground.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content" style="display:block;width:100%;height:600px">
```

---

I can't see the div background img, please help!

I have tried to solve the problem, with no success.

Comment: This is very likely to be an issue with using a relative path.  When you open up the javascript console or network tab of the developer tools, does it show a 404 error for that image?

Answer (score 0):

To reference a class, use the '.' prefix before "content" in the CSS.
So it would become:

```
.content {
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

As you now say the '.' was mistakenly missing from your CSS, some things to try:

- Ensure that the file exists in the specified location.
- Check that the div isn't behind anything else.

Comment: i didnt copy the '.' by mistake .                                                                                       i have it in my code still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if file is present.Go to Your index page and try putting path to image into url. JPG and JPEG are not the same thing
2. Do not use just background-image , instead of that use for example  : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp
3. Also if you are not doing some CSS dark magic there is not reason to put CSS in tag and in style.
4. I checked Your code and it should be working. Problem is with Your picture. Try to pass more HTML code. There is a chance that some other DIV is covering it

Comment: tried anything you told me to do.still having the same problem

Comment: If you want , send me Your HTML file on email i will try to figure it out. keprta.martin@gmail.com

Comment: I tried Your code. Definetly You have som problem with accessing that image.